# My method Links() does not work?

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

My pagination function: {{ $taches->links() }} gives the ErrorException (below) in the following path: View: C:\wamp64\www\Application\resources\views\groupe\tache.blade.php

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method links does not exist.

Any help on this really appreciated.

In controller:

```
public function index($id){
    $projet = Projet::find($id);
    $taches = $projet->tache()->paginate(1);
    return view('groupe.tache',['projet' => $projet, 'taches' => $taches]);
}
```

in view

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ $projet->tache->links() }}  </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

projet -tache relation model

```
    public function projet()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Projet','projet_id');
}

    public function tache() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Tache','projet_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the project-tache relation from your model?

Comment: can you please check again my question , i updated

Comment: the function is work pefectly .. its show all the tache in view ..but whene i use the paginate the {{ $taches->links() }} gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Use `$taches->links()` instead of `$projet->tache->links()`.